# Append Variables to URL on page load | javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a variable that is stored within a JS file to a URL that is a `<script>` section which is within my HTML.

How do I talk between the my HTML script tag and my JS file?

My thinking on this is

```
var postUrl = $('img').attr('src', 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nands-test-logs/b.png' + addedParam);
```

The `addedParam` variable is within a JS file that is referenced.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: If the JS file which defines `addedParam` and sets its value is included before that line of code, then what you have should work. Is there a specific problem you have?

Comment: And what is e.g value of `addedParam`??? Are you facing scope issue or what? Error in console? Etc... If you want help, you need to provide MCVE or at least be more specific regarding your question because actually, it doesn't really make sense

Comment: you should add <script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script> to talk between HTML and JS file  .

Comment: @D4S I have that and I get back addedParam is undefined...

Comment: @Filth make sure your javascript file path and scope of 'addedParam'  variable.

Comment: Here is the script https://jsfiddle.net/64je2z4n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps will make your code work

1. Put your javascript file in `<head>` section.
2. Call HTML script within document ready  as below

   `<script>
   $(document).ready(funciton(){
      var postUrl = $('img').attr('src', 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nands-test-logs/b.png' + addedParam);
   });
   </script>`

Comment: I tried doing that and I get addedParam is undefined. That variable is within a function if that helps?

Comment: Make sure your variable `addedParam` is declared global. Means outside any block. It has to be declared as `var addedParam;` only once globally

Comment: Thank you, I changed that and still no luck... Have a look at the fiddle here and search for addedParam - I'm pretty certain I've now made the variable global - https://jsfiddle.net/64je2z4n/

Comment: Like i said, the variable is inside a function block. It has to be put outside as in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/64je2z4n/1/

Comment: Ah right! Now I understand, thanks a heap Thanga - simple thing really. Will read up on global / non global variables